# How come python's __repr__ of a dict is more readable than its __str__?

Tags: python, ipython, repr

See the below example:

```
In [33]: test = {x:str(x)*10 for x in range(10)}

In [35]: print test
{0: '0000000000', 1: '1111111111', 2: '2222222222', 3: '3333333333', 4: '4444444444', 5: '5555555555', 6: '6666666666', 7: '7777777777', 8: '8888888888', 9: '9999999999'}

In [34]: test
Out[34]: 
{0: '0000000000',
 1: '1111111111',
 2: '2222222222',
 3: '3333333333',
 4: '4444444444',
 5: '5555555555',
 6: '6666666666',
 7: '7777777777',
 8: '8888888888',
 9: '9999999999'}
```

The output of the print function (__str__) is objectively less readable than the __repr__ output. It's a long line that will word-wrap into multiple lines with no spacing. Both of them are unambiguous enough to let you reconstruct the object with their output.

Wouldn't the opposite outputs make sense here, with __repr__ being the compact representation and __str__ having the more readable linebreaks?

Comment: This will blow your mind: `repr(test) == str(test)`

Comment: Surely this is just IPython being helpful.

Comment: because `repr` is optimized by ipython.

Comment: Oh damn. You're right

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is just an ipython thing. In the standard Python 3.7 REPL this is the output:

```
>>> test = {x:str(x)*10 for x in range(10)}
>>> print(test)
{0: '0000000000', 1: '1111111111', 2: '2222222222', 3: '3333333333', 4: '4444444444', 5: '5555555555', 6: '6666666666', 7: '7777777777', 8: '8888888888', 9: '9999999999'}
>>> test
{0: '0000000000', 1: '1111111111', 2: '2222222222', 3: '3333333333', 4: '4444444444', 5: '5555555555', 6: '6666666666', 7: '7777777777', 8: '8888888888', 9: '9999999999'}
>>>
```

The output is the same if we execute this as a "normal" script:

```
test = {x: str(x) * 10 for x in range(10)}
print(str(test))
#  {0: '0000000000', 1: '1111111111', 2: '2222222222', 3: '3333333333', 4: '4444444444', 5: '5555555555', 6: '6666666666', 7: '7777777777', 8: '8888888888', 9: '9999999999'}
print(repr(test))
#  {0: '0000000000', 1: '1111111111', 2: '2222222222', 3: '3333333333', 4: '4444444444', 5: '5555555555', 6: '6666666666', 7: '7777777777', 8: '8888888888', 9: '9999999999'}
```

No line breaks in either the `str` or `repr` representations, as was previously alluded to in the comments:

```
print(repr(test) == str(test))
# True
```

The conclusion is that this is just ipython taking the initiative in making `repr`'s output more human-friendly .

Comment: It’s surely not calling `repr` on the whole thing at all, but decomposing the `dict` on its own.

Answer (score 1):

IPython does that, so `print` does regular stuff, but just naming variable does cool stuff, that's why...

printing `pandas dataframes` with `print` get ugly, and just naming variable does beautifully

Note that [@Aran-Fey says](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53097854/how-come-pythons-repr-of-a-dict-is-more-readable-than-its-str/53097939#comment93091677_53097854):

**"This will blow your mind: `repr(test) == str(test)`"**

Rightfully so, non-IPython interpreters don't makes this happen.